# String.encode() alternative in Ruby 1.8.7 for cleaning input to UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8, sanitization

I just discovered that the String.encode method is only available from Ruby -v 1.9.3 and upwards. I'm working in a Rails environment were I cannot change this. I used this method to correct invalid UTF-8 input.

The only good alternative I've found was through the iconv.conv() method, however iconv is deprecated in newer ruby versions and I would like my code to be smelling like flowers even if/when my sysadmin decides to upgrade.

For reference, the alternative I found from [Here](http://po-ru.com/diary/fixing-invalid-utf-8-in-ruby-revisited/):

```
ic = Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8')
valid_string = ic.iconv(untrusted_string + ' ')[0..-2]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [charlock_holmes](https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes) gem, that covered most of our pre 1.9 needs in encoding.